# C++ scopes and allocation

Tags: c++

If I understand correctly, variables that are not dynamically allocated are supposed to be deleted at the end of their scope.
However, I wanted to try it out with this code (which I think is not correct as I am supposed to use dynamic allocation) :

```
int* function()
{
    int a = 3;
    return &a;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int* a(function());
    std::cout << *a << std::endl; // prints 3
}
```

Why can I still access the value of the variable a by using the pointer returned by the function when it is supposed not to exist anymore ?

Answer (score 0):

`a` and hence the return value from `function` has gone out of scope. You are just lucky.

Just be careful and compile with all the warnings enables - and take heed of those warnings.

Comment: Actually, He is **very unlucky** that the code didn't crash immediately.

Comment: ... Depends on how you see the world

Comment: What do you mean by lucky ? It seems to work every time

Comment: That may be the case in this example. But in the future when using this methodology it will break.

Comment: @MaxV37 try it with a different optimization level, with a different compiler (or compiler version) or on a different platform. It is *not guaranteed to work* so that it does is just pure luck and may break at any time.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you can access the value is pure luck. The code has undefined behaviour (since the variable is destroyed) and the compiler can generate whatever it wants - but you cannot rely on it.